# Phonegap can't detect index.js

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I'm asking you because I'm stuck on something stupid I can't find out ...

I started using phonegap a couple days ago and I was progressing quite well but this morning, my index.html doesn't care my js/index.js anymore !

I have a button that is supposed to fire an alert but when I click the button, nothing happens at all.

I understand I must have moved something wrong but could you please have a look ?

I tried to remove as many useless info as I could.
Here is my HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.url.js"></script>


    <script  type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css" />      
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/AndroidHoloDarkLight.min.css" />


</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
            <h1>My Test App</h1>

        </div>
            <input type="button" name="goBack" id="goBack" onclick="goBack" value="Go Back to the previous View">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the .js :

```
function goBack()
{
alert("test ...");
}
/*$("#bodyPage").ready(function(){

$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    $("#page").bind("pageshow", function(event){
        var url = $.url(document.location);
        var arg1 = url.param("arg1");
        $("#testP").text(arg1);
    });
}
```

I'm learning by myself so I may have misunderstood something but could you please help enlightening me ?
Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: You can place your index.js at same place where phonegap.js and jquery.js is present and check once.

Comment: Why are you loading jquery and jquery mobile each twice??? BTW, should be: `onclick="goBack()"`

Comment: Yeah had these problem, thanks for noticing, though it keeps on bahaving the same way =/ acting just like there is no .js

Comment: might be silly, but can you give us an idea of your file/directory structure?  I see jquery in the root of your project, but index.js in a folder called js.  also, put something like `alert("loaded index.js")` in your index.js to ensure that it is being loaded

Comment: The HTML file is in www/index.html while the js file is in : www/js/index.js
I tried to use that alert line and nothing happened, the js file isn't loaded. I had the same behavior on both phone and browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you've all been pretty useful in helping me getting better in javascript, the problem was much stupider...

In the .js file, I commented code with /* but I didn't use the */ because I thought it didn't matter much since I comment until the end. But I was wrong and I finaly found it thanks to everybody's help.

Have a nice day and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
<input type="button" name="goBack" id="goBack" onclick="goBack" value="Go Back to the previous View">
```

in:

```
<input type="button" name="goBack" id="goBack" onclick="goBack()" value="Go Back to the previous View">
```

Update: There is something wrong in the file structure.

Advice: Do not use jQuery Mobile in mobile applications. Try more lightweight frameworks instead.

Comment: 'been trying as well but no change =/

Comment: Is index.js recognised by the browser?

Comment: No it's not, I can click the button but nothing happens

Comment: Which browser are you using? Try to go in Resources and see if there is your .js file -->http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-yPWcWnzRoNc/Tce7i1CKWDI/AAAAAAAADjI/EEUvgfQ4jN4/s1600/Chrome_resources.png

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///[...]/www/phonegap.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///[...]/www/jquery-1.7.2.js
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL index.js:40

Seems like ou found something

Comment: It seems there's something wrong in file structure.

Comment: Ok I found the error, I commented the end of my file using /* but I wasn't closing it with */ ... I thought this wouldn't matter since the file is over. Thanks a lot for you answer. Maybe you should edit your answer and I'll display the error in the question ? So I can validate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

in yout input tag try `onclick="javascript:goBack();"`

Comment: I tried but unfortunately doesn't change a thing =/

Comment: where you have placed your html file ..? i mean in which folder?

Comment: The HTML file is in www/index.html while the js file is in : www/js/index.js
btw, my js file is only made of these 4 lines, is it enough ? I don't need any header thing ?

Comment: add this function to your html page in a <script> and see if it works.. i will suggest  to use "firebug" to identify the problem , by opening html page in desktop Firefox...

Comment: and for the JS file you have asked, take a look on this.. 
http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=21808

Answer (score 0):

You habve included jquery two time:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
```